# Ploting function word2vec Error 'Word2Vec' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have my word2vec model.
I can use it in order to see the most similars words.
Now i create a function in order to plot the word as vector.
Here my function :

```
def tsne_plot(model):

    labels = []
    tokens = []

    for word in model.wv.key_to_index:
        tokens.append(model[word])
        labels.append(word)
    
    tsne_model = TSNE(perplexity=40, n_components=2, init='pca', n_iter=2500, random_state=23)
    new_values = tsne_model.fit_transform(tokens)

    x = []
    y = []
for value in new_values:
    x.append(value[0])
    y.append(value[1])
    
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16)) 
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.scatter(x[i],y[i])
    plt.annotate(labels[i],
                 xy=(x[i], y[i]),
                 xytext=(5, 2),
                 textcoords='offset points',
                 ha='right',
                 va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

When i call the function, I have the following error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-d0f4ea6902bf> in <module>
----> 1 tsne_plot(model)

<ipython-input-46-b4714ffe935b> in tsne_plot(model)
      5 
      6     for word in model.wv.key_to_index:
----> 7         tokens.append(model[word])
      8         labels.append(word)
      9 

TypeError: 'Word2Vec' object is not subscriptable
```

I really don't how to remove this error. I think it's maybe because the newest version of Gensim do not use array [...].
Thanks for advance !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Gensim 4.0, the `Word2Vec` object itself is no longer directly-subscriptable to access each word. Instead, you should access words via its subsidiary `.wv` attribute, which holds an object of type `KeyedVectors`.

So, replace `model[word]` with `model.wv[word]`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It work indeed. I see that there is some things that has change with gensim 4.0. Have a nice day :)